# Which tools to build a complete interactive mapping application/web application?

Tags: node.js, openlayers, geodjango, mapnik, tilestache

I want too build a web application, and I am looking at the tools I will have to use.
I want to use a real time map
 I'm a thinking about :

**Tilemill** to get .png in order to constitue the background of my maps
or **get data** from a webite in shp files to build layers for this in mapnik.

**Mapnik** Build layers with the data I want to add on my map.

**Mapnik** : Put layers together and generate a map.

**TileStache** : generate tiles for my application.

**Openlayers** : Display my map with tiles in a browser.

Once my map is displayed, I'd like to add interactivity. For example when you go over a line or a circle (a town/ an event), then it gives you the attributes of this object.

But the lines and circles will integrated dirctly to the mapnik map, so I need to add some javascript to make it dynamic and open a pop-up. How do I do this ? Using **Openlayer javascript libraries** or **node.js**.

What is your advice on the question/the way I want to use theese tools?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in a similar situation, so I don't *know* the answer, but from what I've been able to figure out I think you're on the right track.

I started off using the [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/developers/) approach, which simplifies things as long as your data is static. You use [Tilemill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) not only to generate your PNG tiles (once you've used [Carto](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/carto/) to do some nice styling) but also to import your data sets.

TileMill can export your TileJSON and UTFGrid files with the PNG tiles all packaged up and ready to use. Mapbox will then host all that stuff for you, and you can use their [mapbox.js](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.0.4/) library (an extension of [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)) to bring it all together in the browser, with full interactivity. Opening popups would be something you'd do in Javascript in the browser - and if you mean infoWindows (the overlay window that's associated with a map point) then that would be a call to the Leaflet API.

If you're happy to create your layers and import your data offline this approach seems to be really simple and powerful; Mapbox will even render out tiles using multiple layers overlaid - so for example you can see your circles on top of a satellite image, merged into a single PNG.

The problem really comes in when your data needs to be live and you can't therefore prepare it all ahead of time in TileMill. I'm still trying to figure this all out but it does seem as though a combination of TileStache and Mapnik would be able to serve you up the TileJSON, GeoJSON and UTFGrid files you'd need as well as the tiles themselves, in the way you've outlined in the question.

You might also want PostGIS and GeoDjango or similar behind the scenes in order to hold and manage your live data, respectively.

As I said, I'm still trying to actually get my full stack working so I can't vouch for this 100% but if your data is gathered upfront then I'd definitely recommend the TileMill route for simplicity's sake.

I hope that's a help!

Comment: Thanks. What I did in the end (but with a low design) is simply: 1/load layers in openlayer for the background (ex:openstreetmap), 2/load layers using WMS protocol with my data, coming from my PostGIS database thanks to Geoserver 3/import data with WFS protocol from postgis with geoserver in openlayers when the mouse is over the desired feature. 4/Then openlayer has functions to create interactivity, still with geoserver (popup). -- To visualize my data efficiently, I prefer to use QGIS, which is much more simpler (but not oriented client side).

Comment: That's interesting; I'll have a play with those (I've not come into contact with WMS or SFS before). Doesn't it mean that your interaction puts a lot of load onto the server though? That's what UTFGrid was meant to solve.

Comment: @mkornblum Is Tilemill able to generate UTFGrid? I can't find it?

Comment: It seems to generate it behind the scenes and then package it up. Try adding interactivity to something through the interface (they have an example with earthquake zones you can roll over for instance) and then get it onto your mapbox account and inspect the network tab in your browser console...